# Is it possible to use C library in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air, sip, pjsip

I am trying to make an SIP based application running on Adobe AIR using Flex. Can I use the [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) library written in C for my Flex project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can by using [AIR native extensions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/index.html). Quoting the introduction:

> Native Extensions for Adobe AIR are code libraries that contain native code wrapped with an ActionScript API. You can use native extensions in an AIR application to access platform features not supported by AIR, to benefit from native-code-level performance for critical algorithms, and to reuse existing native code libraries.